# hovering over matplotlib node

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying using `networkx` and `matplotlib`, and i'd like to get the name of the node when hovering over it. I am trying to use the mpld3 library but i seem to be getting a recursion error.

```
graph_nx = graph.to_networkx(max_vertices)
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph_nx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(facecolor='#EEEEEE'))
scatter = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph_nx, pos, ax=ax, node_size=120)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph_nx, pos, ax=ax, width=0.5)

labels = graph_nx.nodes().keys()
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(scatter, labels=labels)
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.show()
```

This is what i have right now.

Comment: When you have an error, put it on the post rather just mentioning you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the labels require a list data type. Have you checked if `graph_nx.nodes().keys()` returns a list. You might want to convert it to a list using .tolist().